# Selenium login issue of Auth0/ single sing on using IE 11

Tags: selenium, auth0

I am using the same code for IE 11 and Chrome. using chrome I am able to login without any problem on Auth0. But when I am using IE 11 everything I click the Login button. it is showing " Can't be blank" error message. I validate the value using the get attribute method. it has the value for username and password. But still, it is showing the error message. I have also used javascript to click the login button, javascript to fill out the username and password field. No luck yet. Can anyone suggest what should I do?

Comment: Code trials? Error stack trace? Relevant HTML?

Comment: I think we could use some more information on this. Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: Hi don, the issue is when i put username and password using javascript in IE . I see there is username and password but when i click it think those value as empty. It is only happening for IE for us. We tried chrome and firefox it is working fine